# Class 'ZurmoBaseTest' not found in EmailTemplateTest.php

Tags: php, yii, phpunit

I'm trying to run unit tests on [zurmo](http://zurmo.org/) and I've a problem, when I try the EmailTemplateTest. I get

```
Fatal error: Class 'ZurmoBaseTest' not found in zurmo\app\protected\
modules\emailTemplates\tests\unit\EmailTemplateTest.php on line 42
```

If I try to include it with require it fixes this, but then

```
Fatal error: Class 'BaseTest' not found in zurmo\app\protected\modul
es\zurmo\tests\unit\ZurmoBaseTest.php on line 38
```

and

```
Fatal error: Class 'RedBeanDatabase' not found in zurmo\app\protecte
d\core\tests\unit\BaseTest.php on line 44
```

If I include them both I get the final

```
Fatal error: Class 'Yii' not found in zurmo\app\protected\core\model
s\RedBeanDatabase.php on line 37
```

What's the problem? Am I supposed to run it from some exact location or the installation is not default. I installed it with the settup and the app is working itself.

Answer (score 0):

You bootstrap is likely missing the autoloader of your framework and / or your framework's PHPUnit extension.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for the answer to this one. You should run it via TestSuite.php

```
phpunit TestSuite.php EmailTemplateTest
```

TestSuite.php will include the necessary files for you.

http://zurmo.org/tutorials/running-unit-tests-explained